# Help with small dish antenna on 2m/440

Tags: vhf, uhf

I have an oblong dish network antenna that I want to convert to 2m/440 usage.

I have seen the one for the 14 foot dish but I do not have one.  Not sure if I should wind a coil and mount it in the center as the transmitting antenna or make some cuts in the dish itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share a picture? (if in doubt how, upload to imgur.com and paste link here)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the physical aperture size of your dish will make it a poor 2 meter antenna and a marginal 440 antenna.

Instead of treating it like a dish antenna, you may wish to consider making it a slotted aperture antenna. This makes a reasonable stealth antenna if that is your goal. QST had an article within the last six months, detailing such a design.